# i tried exception to hold the Application but it says(UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment )

Tags: python

this is my code which is creating issues i just want my microphone to keep trying to listen

```
def takeCommand(self):
    print("listening")
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = MySiri.listner.listen(source,phrase_time_limit=3)

    try:
        result = MySiri.listner.recognize_google(audio)
        print(result)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        self.speak("sorry,repeat")
    return result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is if your code breaks in `result = MySiri.listner.recognize_google(audio)` & goes into exception there's no var named `result` in exception, so try this instead

```
def takeCommand(self):
    print("listening")
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = MySiri.listner.listen(source,phrase_time_limit=3)

    try:
        result = MySiri.listner.recognize_google(audio)
        print(result)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        result = 'sorry, repeat'
        self.speak("sorry,repeat")
    return result
```